# How to generate a sequence with a given pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I’m trying to make a loop that makes this list of numbers: `[1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,6]`

Comment: Is there a specific pattern to be seen in this sequence? It would be useful to disambiguate the pattern you want to generate

Comment: Yes. It goes up three times and then steps down ones. From there it starts again. Like a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you seem to be describing is `+1, +1, +1, -1, ...`. Here is a straightforward way to generate it.

```
def pattern(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        lst.extend(range(i, i + 3))
        lst.append(i + 1)
    return lst

print(pattern(7)) # [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6]
```

A slightly more general way is to create a generator representing the infinite sequence.

```
import itertools

def pattern():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        yield i + 1
        yield i + 2
        yield i + 1
        i += 2

print(*itertools.islice(pattern(), 12)) # 1 2 3 2 3 4 5 4 5 6 7 6
```